# Node.js calling function from other function not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

Profile.js code goes as below

```
'use strict';
var service = require('../services/Profile');
class Profile {
    updateProfile(req, resp) {
        this.updateUserDetails(req, resp);
    }
     updateUserDetails(req, resp){
        var admin = req.body;
        resp.json({"success":true,"message":"User Updated"});
    }
}
module.exports = new Profile();
```

server.js code goes as below

```
...... Some code -------

var profile = require("./controllers/Profile")
app.put("/api/profile", auth, profile.updateProfile);


...... Some code -------
```

When I make the call <>/api/profile  I am getting error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateUserDetails' of undefined ,
 (at line number of code this.updateUserDetails(req, resp);)
```

Since there is some common logic so I need to move to some function and want to call in different place, but I am getting this error. I am new to node js looking for help.

Comment: Can you show us in your `server.js` how you load your class ? I guess you just do `const profile = require('Profile.js');`

Comment: I have update the question

Comment: Also, you should export the class rather than an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the function out of class and using it, it worked

```
'use strict';
var service = require('../services/Profile');
class Profile {
    updateProfile(req, resp) {
        updateUserDetails(req, resp);
    } 
}
function updateUserDetails(req, resp){
        var admin = req.body;
        resp.json({"success":true,"message":"User Updated"});
    }

module.exports = new Profile();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic misunderstanding of how `this` works in javascript. I'd suggest you search stackoverflow for the phrase `"how this works in javascript"`.

As for your code, you either need to do this:

```
app.put("/api/profile", auth, function (req,res) {
    profile.updateProfile(req,res)
});
```

or this:

```
app.put("/api/profile", auth, profile.updateProfile.bind(profile));
```

Comment: But it dont work, for any other call backs inside updateProfile, any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

change your code to:

```
var prof = new Profile();
module.exports = prof;
```

and then use it in the other method like this:

```
class Profile {
    updateProfile(req, resp) {
        prof.updateUserDetails(req, resp);
    }
```

this should work just fine.